# NodeJS/AngularJS - Reading Array of Objects from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, angularjs, mongodb

I've got an issue reading a nested array from **JSON(BSON from MongoHQ) using Node and Angular.**

**JSON snippet**: http://pastie.org/9305682. Specifically look for the edges array.

**Mongoose model**: http://pastie.org/9305685

Basically I call the character from the DB and then attempt to log it to the console with
**console.log(char);** before sending it back to the angular call with **res.json(char);** 'char' is the returned character from the databased saved as my mongoose model.

Attempting to log the character to the console. **I get everything looking normal except for the portions with the nested "effects" arrays**. Anywhere they show up I receive the following:

```
edges:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 [ { name: 'Super Hacker', notes: '', effects: [Object] },                                                                                                                                                                                    
   { name: 'Witty', notes: '', effects: [Object] },                                                                                                                                                                                           
   { name: 'Attractive', notes: '', effects: [Object] },                                                                                                                                                                                      
   { name: 'Encyclopedic Memory',                                                                                                                                                                                                             
     notes: 'Prereq: d8 Smarts',                                                                                                                                                                                                              
     effects: [Object] },                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
   { name: 'Daywalker', notes: '', effects: [Object] },                                                                                                                                                                                       
   { name: 'Tough', notes: '', effects: [Object] } ],
```

**From here if I try to call it with:**

From NodeJS - console.log(char[0].edges[0].effects[0].type); - **Returns undefined.**

From Angular View - {{cur_char.edges[0].effects[0].type}} -  **Displays nothing.**

Thanks in advance for the help. Let me know if I can provide more in.

Comment: Have you tried just console.log(char[0].edges[0].effects[0]), to see if the object is being returned as JSON?

Comment: Calling this I get [object Object].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're asking is how to see more depth to the object in the console output.  You can use `util.inspect` to print out more information:

```
console.log(util.inspect(char, { depth: 5 }));
```

By default `util.inspect` only goes to a depth of 2 which explains why you can only see the contents of the array (1) and the primitive properties of each element in the array (2).

See: http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options

Comment: Okay, I've tried this out. I still get the same result of [object] though.

Comment: It appears to work for me.  Here is a script I created to test it out.  On screen I see `effects` displayed in console for all the edges. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f8f29903010a6f425e03  I named the file `char.js` and ran it with: `node char.js`

Comment: Hmm yeah doing it that way works for me too. I believe the issue was that the effects array needed to be treated as its own schema. Regardless I've decided just to keep effects as a single array of strings instead of anbarray of objects. Thanks for the help!